# Windows Server 2008 Create Symbolic Link, updated Security Policy still gives privilege error

Tags: security, windows-server-2008, symbolic-link

Windows Server 2008, RC2.  I am trying to create a symbolic/soft link using the mklink command:

```
mklink /D LinkName TargetDir
e.g. c:\temp\>mklink /D foo bar
```

This works fine if I run the command line as Administrator.  However, I need it to work for regular users as well, because ultimately I need another program (executing as a user) to be able to do this.

So, I updated the Local Security Policy via secpol.msc.  Under "Local Policies" > "User Rights Management" > "Create symbolic links", I added "Users" to the security setting.

I rebooted the machine.  It still didn't work.  So I added "Everyone" to the policy.  Rebooted.  And STILL it didn't work.

What on earth am I doing wrong here?  I think my user is even an Administrator on this box, and running plain command line even with this updated policy in place still gives me:

```
You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.
```

---

It's not looking promising for me:http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasecurity/thread/cb593ad0-9edc-4cd1-bb67-46c360b45f91

Sounds like others have experienced this problem, and I've yet to find a resolution.  Anyone out there been able to programmatically create soft/sybmolic links?

Comment: Have you tried Junction instead of mklink?

Comment: @Hello71:  MKLINK in Vista onwards replaces JUNCTION from the Win Server 2003 Resource Kit. It has more functionality for the new NTFS abilities (symlinks).

Comment: @jason404: I was talking about the [`junction.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) from Sysinternals by Mark Russinovich.

Comment: @Hell071: Oh yes, I was mixing it up with LINKD.  However, both LINKD and JUNCTION are not as much use as MKLINK on Vista/Win7/2008/2008 R2.

Comment: Looks like you might need to use `mklink /j` instead of /d for the expected behaviour

Answer (score 1):

have not tried this but if if user A has the symbolic link priv, then open up a cmd and do

runas /user:domain\a cmd

then within that windows try the mklink

all users, even admins run with limited permissions on 08+ you need to elevate 1st.  Don't really hold out a lot of hope on this working!

Comment: thanks for the tip - I'm actually having problems getting runas to work for me - it keeps giving me "the system cannot find the file specified" errors: c:>runas /user:domain\username "mlink /D name target".  Of course, ultimately I need this scriptable, and the password propmpt for said user makes that hard.  I think you may be right about not holding out a lot of hope!

Comment: try to run just the cmd elevated then run mklink within that session

Comment: ah, interesting.  That did the trick.  Now, if only I could do it without runas since I want to script it!

Comment: hopefully you can use powershell, if so then checkout
 get-credentials

Comment: why does it need to be scripted?  I don't see the reasoning behind this.

Comment: +1, I had this problem on Windows 2k8R2, and this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with this Security Policy setting and the Administrator group.  Maybe it is what you are experiencing as well.

If the user(s) you added are member of the Administrator group, then this setting has no effect. Removing them from the Admin group fixes this issue.

Comment: I confirm that this is the case on W 8.1

Comment: It is not a bug but intended UAC behavior: _The new token is stripped of all the privileges assigned to the user except those listed in Figure 9 (Bypass traverse checking, Shut down the system, Remove computer from docking station, Increase a process working set, Change the time zone)_ [TechNet Magazine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows 7, but was able to run the CMD window as an admin and get it to work by following these instructions:

> 1. Click the Start Button.
> 2. Type `cmd` in the search box at the bottom.
> 3. Press the `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` keys all at once.
>
> Note: This opens up the command prompt
>   as Administrator. If you don't do
>   this, you'll get a error saying that
>   there are insufficient permissions to
>   create the symbolic link later on.

http://www.inkplant.com/code/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-in-windows-vista.php

Comment: Didn't know you can ctrl-shift-enter to run as admin, nice trick. But as I stated in the question, ultimately the command needs be be executable from a program (scripted), without human intervention, so this won't help in that regard.

Answer (score -1):

We are able to create a symlink through a script on Windows 2008 server but had to do one the following:

- Provide `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege` privilege to the user who is running the script
- Turn off UAC